# tally delete cost centre xml format using xml api

Tags: tally

Below is the XML format for creating CostCentre in tally using XML API.

```
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>Import Data</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <IMPORTDATA>
            <REQUESTDESC>
                <REPORTNAME>All Masters</REPORTNAME>
            </REQUESTDESC>
            <REQUESTDATA>
                <TALLYMESSAGE xmlns:UDF="TallyUDF">
                    <COSTCENTRE NAME="NewCostCentre">
                        <NAME>NewCostCentre</NAME>
                    </COSTCENTRE>
                </TALLYMESSAGE>
            </REQUESTDATA>
        </IMPORTDATA>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Can anyone help in delete xml and alter xml formats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this small change in the XML tag **COSTCENTRE** to 'DELETE' -

```
<COSTCENTRE NAME="NewCostCentre" ACTION="DELETE">
```

The rest of the XML remains same.

To alter, set the ACTION attribute to **ALTER**.

Lets say you want to alter the name 'NewCostCentre' to 'OldCostCentre'. The following would be your XML -

```
<COSTCENTRE NAME="NewCostCentre" ACTION="ALTER">
<NAME>OldCostCentre</NAME>
```